# How to Decrypt Oracle Data using Python/PySpark?

Tags: python, oracle, apache-spark, encryption, pyspark

I am migrating data from Oracle to Amazon S3. There are few tables in which selective columns are encrypted using Oracle Encrypt method. I want to decrypt that column's data using PySpark.
I have Key that is used for encryption in Oracle. But I am not getting any way to decrypt Data in Pyspark/Python by using the same Key.

How can I use the same key for decryption in PySpark/Python?

Comment: Which "Oracle Encrypt" method? There are several. You would also need to use _exactly_ the same encryption algorithm. In general what you are attempting to do is extremely difficult, if not impossible - even with the key, this level of encryption is designed to prevent exactly what you're trying to do. Your best bet is to decrypt the data in Oracle using SQL or whatever means is already provided there, before re-encrypting it with Python using an appropriate method/algorithm and moving it to S3.

Comment: Thank @pmdba, I will also check the encryption method used at Oracle.